# Why does time.sleep occur before other functions in python pygame even though I don't want it to, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, pygame, delay

I work on windows and when I use time.sleep it always occurs before any other function.

I tried putting it in other areas but it always has the same problem.

```
def all_cards():
    card.rect.y -= 50
    card.clicked = True

def delete(card1, card2):
    card1.exist = False
    card2.exist = False
    card1.clicked = False
    card2.clicked = False
    card1.rect.y = 275
    card2.rect.y = 0


if card.rect.collidepoint(x, y):
    all_cards()

if example.clicked and example2.clicked:
    time.sleep(1)
    hp -= 5
    image_clickables.remove(example)
    image_clickables.remove(example2)
```

The problem is the first card moves when clicked but when the second card is clicked it has a 2 second delay before it moves up and then it gets deleted at the same time, making it impossible to see it move up.

It should have both cards moved up instantly when clikced then have a 2 second delay and both will get deleted and put back to the original spot for later use, I tried putting time.sleep() in the delete function itself with no avail.

Comment: `time.sleep()` pauses your whole program.  NOTHING happens at all.  If a card was in motion, it will NOT keep moving during the sleep time.  No code executes at all.

Answer (score -1):

**pygame** updates window when pygame.display.update() called. So all codes executed before pygame.display.update() would apply to gui at the same time.

Plus, time.sleep() pauses updating GUI too.

To solve problem use pygame.time.tick() to calculate how many seconds have passed

```
### init function 
# isTimerSet = false

### main loop
deltatime = pygame.time.tick()

if example.clicked and example2.clicked and not isTimerSet:
    timer = 0
    isTimerSet = True
if isTimerSet:
    if timer < 1000:  # 1000ms = 1s
        timer += deltatime
    else:
        isTimerSet = False
        hp -= 5
        image_clickables.remove(example)
        image_clickables.remove(example2)
```